# how do i use ! in message.channel.id when i use it doesn't read it at all

Tags: discord.js

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
 if (message.content === '') {
  if (!message.channel.id === '')
   return (
    message.delete() &&
    message.channel
     .send(
      `<@${message.author.id}>
Goto <#>`
     )
     .then((message) => {
      message.delete({ timeout: 15000 });
     })
   );
  message.lineReply(`${message.author.id}`);
 }
});
```

Comment: I don't understand your question or your code. Could you elaborate on your issue, describe what you're trying to do, show any relevant errors, etc?

Comment: my question is the command work in commands channel and if other channel tell me to go to the right channel
i have to use !message.channel.id right?
now when i use it doesn't read it at all

Comment: It's not `!x === y`, it's `x !== y`. Also, are you sure matching only messages with no content is intentional? Furthermore, why are you using `if (x) return (y && z)` instead of just `if (x) { y; return z }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to make it so that if a user send a message to a specific channel and if its not that specific channel you wanna delete it and send a message right?if so do message.channel.id !== '    ', since !message.channel.id means if its not message.channel.id